# toString for an IntSet for java

Tags: java

```java
public class IntSetImpl implements IntSet {
   
    private boolean [] a = new boolean[101];
    private int size = 0;

    private void validate(int n){
        if (n < 0 || n > 100) 
            throw new RuntimeException("value is out of range.");
    }
    
    public static IntSet makeSet(int[] a){
        IntSet s = new IntSetImpl();
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) 
            s.add(a[i]);
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int n) {
        validate(n);
        if (!a[n]) {
           a[n] = true;
           size++;
        }  
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int n) {
       validate(n);
        if (!a[n]) {
           a[n] = false;
           size--;
        }  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int n) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] toArray() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public IntSet union(IntSet s) {
        IntSetImpl union = new IntSetImpl();     
        boolean a[] = this.a;
        boolean b[] = ((IntSetImpl)s).a;    
        boolean c[] = ((IntSetImpl)union).a; 

        for(int i=0; i<101; i++)  
          c[i] = a[i] | b[i];
        return union;
    }

    @Override
    public IntSet intersect(IntSet s) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public IntSet difference(IntSet s) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{");
        sb.append(size > 0 ? a[size] : "");
        for(int i = 2; i < size; i++)
            sb.append(", ").append(a[i]);
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();

    }
    
}
```

This is my code for an IntSet. The unsupported operations are just methods I haven't written code for. My main problem is the toString method and I don't understand what is wrong with it. Whenever I run the program it prints out my IntSet as just false/true.

```java
IntSet s = IntSetImpl.makeSet(new int[]{5,2,4,5,2,4});

System.out.println(s);
s.remove(20);
s.remove(5);
System.out.println(s);

System.out.println(s.contains(2));
System.out.println(s.isEmpty());
System.out.println(s.contains(20));
```

The code above prints out:

```
{false, true}
{true}
false
false
false
```

It's supposed to print out the numbers that are true not that they are true. Any sort of help with the toString method would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? What is its expected behavior vs observed behavior? Please tell the details of your problem. Please go through the [ask]  link now, followed by the [help] and [tour] links..

Comment: That `a[size]` smells fishy... Array index goes up to `arraySize - 1`

Comment: `private boolean [] a = new boolean[101];` is a `boolean` array, of course `sb.append(", ").append(a[i]);` prints true/false.

Answer (score 2):

You need to print the index, not the `boolean`-value at the index:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(size > 0 ? size : "");
    sb.append("{");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sb.append(", ").append(i);
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That is because you implemented your `IntSet` as a boolean array...
As correctly pointed out in the comments, you also probably wanted to print the size, not `a[size]`, and you probably wanted to start at `0`, so I changed these things as well. I moved the size before the braces, to separate it from the values.

---

Side note: there is also a bug in your `remove()` - the condition appears to be inverted... you only remove when the value is *not* set.

Comment: There are other problems in the `toString()` code, even after appending `i` instead of `a[i]`. Why start from `i = 2`? Why print `a[size]` at all? Your initial phrase is correct, but the code does not work as expected.

Comment: @tucuxi right, thanks I had missed these things

Answer (score 1):

Your code prints boolean values because the `a` array is an array of booleans. It seems you were expecting to print an array of actual integers included in the set. To do that, you have to print the indices of those positions of `a` that are `true`:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (a[i]) {
           // print the index, since that int is in the set
           sb.append(i).append(", ");
        }
    }
    if (sb.length() > 2) { 
        // not empty: remove last ", "
        sb.delete(sb.length() - ", ".length(), sb.length());
    }
    return sb.append("}").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return IntStream.range(0, a.length)
        .filter(i -> a[i])
        .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntSet s = IntSetImpl.makeSet(new int[]{5,2,4,5,2,4});
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output:

```
{2, 4, 5}
```